# How to transfer type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface IDropDownProps {
  items: any[];
  renderItems: (item: any) => React.ReactElement<any>;
}
```

`renderItems` is a function, which takes the item of `items` and return an according React Element.

What I want to do is to pass the type from `items` to `renderItems`, so I can do something like:

```
interface IDropDownProps {
  items: Array<T>;
  renderItems: (item: T) => React.ReactElement<any>;
}
```

Otherwise, I need to cast the type everytime I declare that `renderItems`.

Is it possible and how to do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to define **T** at interface level in your interface though.

```js
interface GenericIf<T> { }
interface IDropDownProps<T> {
    items: Array<T>;
    renderItems: (item: T) => GenericIf<T>;
}
```